# replication multiple databases into one database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Before the question I want to explain what I'm trying to do.
I'm using `SQL Server 2016` and I have 2 databases

```
DataBaseA

DataBaseB
```

In a remote server I created the same databases using the same creation SQL scripts that i used for `DataBaseA` and `DatabaseB`. Then I used the replication service from `SQL Server 2016`. My local database is the publisher and the remote server is the subscriber.

This worked fine.
What I want to do is having one database in the remote server that contains all tables from both databases and the 2 databases replicate to their corresponding tables.

For example

```
[DataBaseA].[dbo].[TableA] ---is Replicated into-->[AggregatedDataBase].[dbo].[TableA]

[DataBaseB].[dbo].[TableB] ---is Replicated into-->[AggregatedDataBase].[dbo].[TableB]
```

Is this possible? If yes how to do it else what other options to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it is possible..two different publishers can have one subscriber..

> If yes how to do it

Just set up the way you set up replication and while selecting subscriber choose aggregated database

Comment: Hello Thank you for your answer. Do we have 2 subscriptions from the 2 publishers? so I end up with 2 subscriptions from 2 publishers to 1 subscriber?

Comment: What I meant is when I expand the Local Subscription folder in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. am I supposed to see 2 subscriptions or one.  Sorry it's a new concept for me.

Comment: 2 publishers ,2 distributors 1 subscriber